# How to install d3js Haskell package?

Tags: haskell, d3.js, haskell-stack

I'd just like to try the Haskell [d3js](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/d3js) package. Here's what I tried:

```
stack install d3js
```

But it gives the error:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for d3js-0.1.0.0:
    base-4.9.1.0 must match >=4.6 && <4.7 (latest applicable is 4.6.0.1)
```

I tried `stack install base-4.6.0.1`, which doesn't output anything but completes without an error, but I still get the same error when I try `stack install d3js`.

I also tried using cabal:

```
$ cabal install d3js                         

Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: d3js-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of d3js-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.9.1.0/installed-4.9... (conflict: d3js => base>=4.6 && <4.7)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0,
base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0,
base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1,
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1
(constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this dependency issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see, the d3js package has an upper bound on the base package. The base package is the set of modules that ship with a given version of GHC including, e.g., `Prelude`. Because base ships with GHC, you can't install a different version than the one you already have without installing a different GHC.

The d3js package was last (and only) updated in 2013 and its base version bounds indicate that it will only work with GHC 7.6. Unfortunately, Stack did not exist in 2013 and there is no version of stackage that works with GHC 7.6. You may have some success instructing Stack (and thereby Cabal) to ignore the upper version bound and using LTS 2.22 with GHC 7.8.4, which the d3js package might be compatible with despite its upper bound on base, but I have not tested this. You can do this by setting `allow-newer: True` in a stack.yaml file.

It may just be the case, however, that the d3js package is too old to work with the GHCs provided by Stack.

As a last resort, you may be able to rehabilitate it by downloading it locally, updating its bounds (and perhaps fixing any incompatibilities that result), and configuring a stack.yaml file to treat it as both a local package and an extra dependency. See [Local dependency packages](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#local-dependency-packages-extra-dep) in the Stack configuration documentation for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

This package is pretty old, and it has fixed dependency on `base` package (read, compiler version).

I'd start with relaxing that dependency requirement in `d3js.cabal` file and then running build again. if that wouldn't work, you'd need to either hack the code, or use a old compiler (or stack resolver, if you are using stack).